# Removing selective items from ListState

Tags: apache-flink

I am implementing custom operator which has large state (which may not fit in memory). I am trying to use ListState for this purpose.
I am using

```
checkpointedState = context.getOperatorStateStore().getListState(descriptor);
```

as mentioned in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#using-managed-operator-state

Implementation of snapshotState() in the above link clears the checkpointedState and then add elements from in-memory data structure to checkpointedState.

Instead I need something like below in the  snapshotState():

1. Remove specific entries for checkpointedState instead of clear().
2. Add new elements from in-memory data structure to checkpointedState.

Is there any way to selectively remove items from ListState?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, removing specific elements from a `ListState` unfortunately not possible. 
If you want to preserve specific list entries, you have to fetch them into a collection before clearing the `ListState` and reinsert them afterwards again.

In the example that you reference, all state objects are stored in the `bufferedElements` variable and only inserted into the `ListState` when a checkpoint is done. That means, the complete operator state is always stored on the JVM heap in `bufferedElements`. You can store parts of the operator state also in the `ListState` (instead of holding it on the heap) but it will be quite expensive to access individual elements because you have to traverse an iterator.